# Angular ng-repeat & ng-model with firebase not updating

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm using angularfire and am at the last stage of my poll app where someone casts their vote, clicks submit and updates the count(or mark is what I call it) in the quesiton. Here's my data model:

```
"-JOiDEYd8ANSv9jbL5qJ" : {
    "question" : "Coffee or Tea?",
    "options" : [ {
      "mark" : 0,
      "option" : "Coffee"
    }, {
      "mark" : 0,
      "option" : "Tea"
    } ]
  },
  "-JOiD7pd0fpY_lvYr74s" : {
    "question" : "Bagels or Waffles?",
    "options" : [ {
      "mark" : 0,
      "option" : "Bagels"
    }, {
      "mark" : 0,
      "option" : "Waffles"
    } ]
  },
```

Here's my html for what a user sees when they take a poll:

```
     <form role="form" ng-submit="pollSubmit()">
        <div class = "form-group" ng-repeat="option in selected.options">
            <input type="radio" name = "answer" ng-value="1" ng-model="option.mark" > {{option.option}}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="btn btn-primary btn-xs pull-left" type="submit" value="Submit Poll">
        </div>
    </form>
```

When I test {{option.mark}} in the html, the value of mark increments every time I select the radio button and doesn't reset to 0 when I click the other option. I want the mark on the back end to go up by one when I actually submit it. So how do I make so my radio button only picks one option and doesn't keep incrementing the mark by one when someone clicks on the radio button before they even submit it.

Here's my controller

```
'use strict';

angular.module('controllers', [])
        .controller('homeCtrl', ['$scope', '$firebase', function ($scope, $firebase){
            $scope.total = null;

            var ref = new Firebase('https://resplendent-fire-5367.firebaseio.com/');
            $scope.polls = $firebase(ref);

            $scope.title = 'Active Polls';

            $scope.select = function(poll){
                $scope.selected = poll;
            };


            $scope.pollSubmit = function (){
            if(confirm('Submit response?')){
                $scope.polls.$update({

                })
            }else{
                return;
            }
        };


        }]);
```

Comment: Are you supposed to be updating an empty object?

Comment: No, sorry I'm still not quite sure how the $update works with ng-model in ng-repeat. How do I get the options.mark in the $update object? do I need to set it to a $scope.mark variable first before I could put it into the pollSubmit function?